# Passport Js is sending error Bad request as response

Tags: javascript, mongodb, passport.js

```
app.post("/register", isLogged ,function(req, res){
var newUser = new User(
    {
        username: req.body.username,
        firstname: req.body.firstname,
        lastname: req.body.lastname,
        avatar: req.body.avatar,
        email: req.body.email

});
User.register(newUser, req.body.password, function(err, user){
    if(err){
        return res.redirect("/register");
        console.log(err);
    }
    passport.authenticate("local")(req, res, function(){
        req.flash("success","Welcome to the pharmacist's diary " +  user.username+ "!" );
        res.redirect("/records");
    });
});
```

Why is this route not working properly and keep sending the same message 'Bad request'.

```
function isLogged(req, res, next){
if(req.isAuthenticated()){
    req.flash("error", "You are already logged in!");
    res.redirect("/records");
}else {
     return next();
}
```

}
This is the isLogged code (middleware used)

Comment: the code for isLogged ?

Comment: Done! Please help.

Comment: if you remove it does it still send Bad request?

Comment: yes It does and the thing is if i remove rest of the entries except for usename and password this code works perfectly fine.

Comment: maybe it is an issue with the avatar? what is it? image?

Comment: yes it is, but i have assigned adefault value in schema
avatar : {type:String , default: "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/10/16/21/52/avatars-2858666_960_720.png"},

Comment: it gives 404 btw

Comment: oh Thats because when you seacrh this link by clicking on it, it adds " at the end of your url :P

Comment: a ok didn't notice

Comment: and you use body-parser right?

Comment: yes, This code works perfectly fine if i remove rest of the entries like "firstname", "lastname"

Comment: let me write this code from scratch and if the error still persists i will let you know. Thanks for your time